# Best way, how to convert 32-byte Keccak hashes to positive numbers up to maximum?

Tags: hash, keccak

I have 32-byte Keccak hashes and I have some maximum number, for example `500`, how to uniformly convert those hashes to pseudo-random positive numbers up to that maximum? 
I mean I have for example 100 quite random hashes and I want to distribute them so the result would be something like 80 numbers hit once, 19 twice and 1 hit three times (I guess something like that), somehow uniform distribution. 
The maximum can be over 32-bits, so I need to use 64-bit integers.

Some approaches come to my mind: 
a) always take first 8 bytes, convert them to 64-bit integer and use modulo 500 on them, 
b) sum 1st 8 bytes, 2nd 8 bytes, 3rd 8 bytes and 4th 8 bytes to 64-bit integer and use modulo 500, 
c) something better?

I know that modulo is not the best for uniform distribution, because it slightly prefers numbers at the beginning of the range, but I think I google how to overcome that by myself and I think it's not even a big deal.

The other thing I am not sure about is whether all the bits in Keccak hashes are quite uniformly distributed, but I guess they should be. I hope that some bit doesn't favor 0s or 1s so some numbers don't get an advantage during my conversion.

Comment: Is this question basically "how can I decode a base 64 string (which happens to be produced by keccak) then deserealize that into some set of ints?"?

Comment: I don't know what is inside Keccak, I use it as 32 bytes. I put some example hash that could be shown, but I thought that inside every byte, there could be 0-255.

Comment: So your question is "what is the optimal strategy to get as many values sampled uniformly at random from my target range out of a given random string with bitwise uniformly random distribution"?

Comment: If you're asking how to get a uniform distribution from values which may not be uniformly distributed... Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing#Hashing_integers?

Comment: The input should be clear, it's 32-byte Keccak hash and I want to uniformly distribute it over a range of numbers. Edited question.

Comment: @jadb Maybe it's relevant, but on the first look I would say that my problem is less generic, I already know I have 32 bytes and the output has to be up to a maximum and the "maximum possible" maximum is up to 8-bytes, highest 64-bit integer is 'ffffffffffffffff'.

Comment: @jadb But you can count that the maximum will be much smaller than the "maximum possible" maximum, up to something like '0000000004ffffff'.

Comment: You're looking for a non-cryptographic hash map. This question should be moved.

Answer (score 5):

Your "32-byte Keccak hash" doesn't look like a canonical, binary Keccak output, but rather appears to be encoded with some [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) variant—to me it appears to be the MIME version.  Your comments on the matter confuse me whether that is the case or not; you should check your language or library's documentation.

If it's Base64 then it appears to be encoding a 18 bytes of raw binary output, which is 144 bits.  This is a unusual output size.  I would double check how your software is generating that output, and verify that all of that Base64 string really reflects a 144-bit Keccak output, and that there aren't some constant bytes being prefixed or suffixed to it.  Again, your description and comments are not helpful in this regard.

---

Taking the modulo is fine in practice if you do it over a large enough input set. 
 Appendix B of [NIST SP 800-185](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-185.pdf) contains a recommendation that uses modulo to convert the output of an extendable output or variable length hash function into a near-uniform natural number $0 ≤ n < R$ for arbitrary $R$.  The trick is that they make sure to do it over a hash output that is *at least* 128 bits longer than the number of bits needed to encode values in the output range:

1. Compute $k = \lceil\log_2(R)\rceil + 128$, where $\lceil\log_2(R)\rceil$ is the number of whole bits needed to encode $R$ distinct values.  For $R = 500$, this is $k = 9 + 128 = 137$.
2. Hash your input to an output $Z$ with length of at least $k$ bits.  Since your outputs are at least 144 bits, they meet this requirement.
3. Convert $Z$ to some "bigint" data type (arbitrary precision integers, check library support in your language; e.g., in Java it's [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)).  The *bits_to_integer* algorithm they detail in the document just parses $Z$ as a binary numeral with least significant bits first, although that later detail is not critical (e.g., Java `BigInteger` parses them in the opposite order, and that's just fine).
4. Take $N = \mathit{bits\_to\_integer}(Z) \mod R$ as your result.

The trick that allows them to use modulo is that they're willing to accept a biased distribution if they can guarantee the bias is astronomically small.  That's why they insist on taking a hash output 128 bits longer than the number of bits needed to encode $R$.  Suppose we used $R = 500$ but $k = 9$ (instead of the recommended $k = 137$).  The problem here is that since $2^k = 2^9 = 512$, when you take the modulo, 488 of the values have a probability of $1/512$ but 12 of them have a probability of $2/512$—they're twice as likely as the others.

Now suppose we take $k = 10$ instead, so $2^k = 1,024$.  Now when you take modulo 500, there are 476 values in the range have a probability of $2/1,024$ but 24 of them have probability of $3/1,024$—they're only 50% more likely than the rest.  For $k = 11$, $2^k = 2,048$ so you get 452 values with probability $4/2,048$ and 48 with $5/2,048$ (only 25% more likely), and so on.  By the time you get to $k = 137$ the bias is negligible; footnote 12 of the appendix gives:

$$
|\mathrm{Prob}(N=t) - 1/R| ≤ 2^{-w}
$$

...where $w ≥ \lceil\log_2(R)\rceil + 128$.

Comment: I updated the question, it is 32-byte Keccak hash, just the example was not good enough (I wanted it to look humanly readable..).

Answer (score -3):

Why not use method in the format keeping encryption.
Sorry, it is format-preserving encryption. This is the wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption
Its method can make the probability of each number be the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean "format-preserving encryption". Either way, you should try to go into more detail in your answer, or at least include a link to the relevant technique.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the changes suggested by Ella or your post will keep accumulating downvotes.

Comment: Sorry, it is format-preserving encryption. This is the wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption